# MySql (Aurora) transpose issues (getting null)

Tags: mysql, database, transpose, amazon-aurora

I have a table like this in MySQL (Aurora):

```
A    B    C
1   100   60
1   102   40
```

My end goal is to transpose this and make it look like this:

```
A   B_1   C_1   B_2   C_2
1   100   60    102    40
```

My query is:

```
SELECT Table.A,
MAX(Table.B) AS `B_1`,
(CASE WHEN Table.B = MAX(Table.B) then Table.C END) AS `C_1`,
MIN(Table.B) AS `B_2`,
(CASE WHEN Table.B = MIN(Table.B) THEN Table.C END) AS `C_2` 
FROM
TABLE 
GROUP BY Table.A
```

But I am getting results as :

```
A   B_1   C_1   B_2   C_2
1   100   null  102    40
```

Can someone help me fix this null issue?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the result it looks like you want the `B_1` value to be `min(B)` and `C_1` to be the corresponding `C` value from the same row. Likewise the `B_2` value to be `max(B)` and `C_2` to be the corresponding `C` value from the same row.

In your query you have normal columns appearing in `SELECT` without including them in the `GROUP BY`. This will result an error in newer MySQL (and in all other databases).

You can first calculate the `MIN(B)` and `MAX(B)` and then join result with table again to pick up the `C` columns.

```
select minb as 'B_1',
       max(c1) as 'C_1',
       maxb as 'B_2',
       min(c2) as 'C_2'
from (
  select 
    s.minb, 
    if (s.minb=m.B, m.C, null) as c1,
    s.maxb, 
    if (s.maxb=m.B, m.C, null) as c2
  from test m
    join (
      select A,
        min(B) as `minb`,
        max(B) AS `maxb`
      from test
      group by A
    ) as s on s.A=m.A
  ) as q
group by minb, maxb
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=920032a2177a2cba0b6cdc0b7a9a2a19)